# Execution failed for task ':app:lintAnalyzeDebug'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, github-actions, lint

Currently I have stuck on this exception.

When I build the **kotlin application** in Android studio then it works perfectly fine... but in github actions the gradle workflow gives this error.

I have tried also tried to do the following in app level build.gradle > android > lintOptions

- checkReleaseBuilds false
- abortOnError false

But all these solutions doesn't work for me.

The error generated is the following

```
> Task :driver:lintAnalyzeDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
* What went wrong:
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
Execution failed for task ':driver:lintAnalyzeDebug'.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':driver:debugUnitTestCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:.
     Required by:
78 actionable tasks: 78 executed
         project :driver

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 27s
##[error***Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution but I'm explaining here also just in case if anyone needs...

As the error is mentioning that we have no **junit testing file**, so we just have to add dependencies for junit testing

You can add these in your **app level** `build.gradle` and modify versions accordingly

```
    // For Junit testing of project
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
```